# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token multiple form functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added the following submit function to my .js file:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {


event.preventDefault();

  var data = $( this ).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "content/rev/a_submit.php",
            data: "data=" + data,
            console.log(data);
            success: function(result){
                $("#acct_content").html(result);
             }
        });
});
```

When doing that I got this error upon page load:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . "

The function worked though, When I hit submit it submits the data I'd expect it to.

But, It prevents these 2 other form functions from not working:

```
$("form").ready(function() {
    var sap = $(this).attr('id');

    forecast_calc(sap);

});
```

and

```
$("form").change(function() {
    var sap = $(this).attr('id');

    forecast_calc(sap);

});
```

If I comment out the submit function everything works fine.

Kind of lost/frustrated here.

Thanks,

Comment: I suspect `console.log` is the issue. Can you try commenting that line?

Comment: If you are submiting the form via ajax, you should use a input button instead of an input submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), like the one passed to `$.ajax()`, don't allow for statements to be included directly under them.

The `console.log(data);` just needs to be separated from it:

```
var data = $( this ).serialize();

console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    // ...
});
```